# Not_Able to Call next Activity

Tags: java, android

```
package com.em.progressb;

public class progressb extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    ProgressDialog dialog;
    int increment;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Button startbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startbtn);
        startbtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void onClick(View view) { 

        // get the increment value from the text box
        EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.increment);
        // convert the text value to a integer
        increment = Integer.parseInt(et.getText().toString());

        dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        dialog.setCancelable(true);
        dialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        // set the progress to be horizontal
        dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        // reset the bar to the default value of 0
        dialog.setProgress(0);

        // get the maximum value
        EditText max = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.maximum);
        // convert the text value to a integer
        int maximum = Integer.parseInt(max.getText().toString());
        // set the maximum value
        dialog.setMax(maximum);
        // display the progressbar
        dialog.show();

        // create a thread for updating the progress bar
        Thread background = new Thread (new Runnable() {
           public void run() {
               try {
                   // enter the code to be run while displaying the progressbar.
                   //
                   // This example is just going to increment the progress bar:
                   // So keep running until the progress value reaches maximum value
                   while (dialog.getProgress()<= dialog.getMax()) {
                       // wait 500ms between each update
                       Thread.sleep(500);

                       // active the update handler
                       progressHandler.sendMessage(progressHandler.obtainMessage());
                   }
               } catch (java.lang.InterruptedException e) {
                   // if something fails do something smart

               }
           }
        });

        // start the background thread
        background.start();

        progressb o1 = new progressb();
        o1.onPause();


 if(dialog.getProgress()==dialog.getMax())
 {    
      Intent i = new Intent(this, ShowMyDialog.class);
         this.startActivity(i);
 }   


    }

    // handler for the background updating
    Handler progressHandler = new Handler() {
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            dialog.incrementProgressBy(increment);
        }
    };
}
```

This is my code of 1st activity.it contains progress bar,as progress reached max limit i want to call 2nd activity and also i have written intent to call next activity.
but its not working.please help me to solve this..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move your code which calls the next activity to the handler. The bg thread that you've created runs *parallel* to the UI thread.

Comment: Just what i said in the answer. *Move your code which calls the next activity to the handler*

Comment: i have moved the calling activity code to handler but it gives this error=The constructor Intent(new Handler(){}, Class<ShowMyDialog>) is undefined

Comment: Don't use *this* instead use *progressb.this*. Do you know Java programming ?

Comment: @reno thank you sir.....but again after reaching progress bar max value same current activity get called..2nd(ShowMyDialog) activity is not get called.

Comment: first you did not do a dialog.dismiss. Second you have to put traces to make sure startActivity is called in your handler when maxvalue is reached.

Comment: but Dialog box got vanished after reaching max value but it gets call to current activity again so is it necessary to use dialog.dismiss....now i have put breakpoint n debugging the code.....